# How to use fspy (linux)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, monitoring

Maybe someone knows how to configure and use fspy on linux. I read also the man page and the help page. I will try some commands to  refine the configuration, though.

On Debian it may be found on the regular repository.

I tried to run the command:

> fspy etc > fspyLog.txt

Could I configure it to give me a live-message on who changed what and where ?

> FSpy is an easy to use linux filesystem activity monitoring tool which is meant to be small, fast and to handle system resources conservative. You can apply filters, use diffing and your own output format in order to get the best results.

Comment: You've read the `man` page, what *specifically* don't you understand? What - *equally specifically* - are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm still not clear on *what you're actually trying to do with `fspy`*. And if it's general leanrning info you're looking for, it's worth noting: "Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. [Here are a few suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/) on how to properly ask this type of question. " *(emphasis changed)*

Comment: For example I want to monitor "etc" folder, to see if changes are made on it (deleting, adding, changing files). Which command should I use ? It's a problem of usage. I'm sorry if it seems a learning question. I wished I could use it on my own system. Hope it's okay.

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1200250/edit) with that (or other) to include that or whatever specific scenario you have in mind, preferably also including what/why you want to monitor eg `/etc`/. At the moment it's quite vague on what you are trying to achieve.